# Decrement and increment with simple array example in C

Tags: c, arrays

I started learning programming about few months ago, with language C at the college. Today, I tried to do something but the results in editor didn't show correct result. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[7]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int x,y,z;
    x=--a[5];     //In my opinion I got the result 5, because at the index of 5
                  //is element with value of 6, I decremented that number and got 5
    y=a[3]+a[x];  //a[3]+a[5] in this case, I get a[8], and value for that index is 9
    z=a[x++];     //I do this: a[5++], switched the value of x which is 5 and increment, and at the index of 5 was value of 6, I think
    printf("%d,%d,%d",x,y,z);
}
```

In my editor, the results are: `6,9,5`
In my case I got the results: `5,9,6`

I know that it is a useless question but I can't solve the problem.
Maybe is about operation with increment and decrement.

Comment: "a[3]+a[5] in this case,i get a[8],and value for that index is 9" - okay, how did you come up with any of that?

Comment: "In my editor,the results is 6,9,5" - An editor does not execute C code. What is your specific problem? Which operator is unclear and cannot be found by a simple search?

Comment: @Olaf He's probably using an integrated IDE like Visual Studio, so the editor executes the code.

Comment: `a[3] + a[x]` is not the same thing as `a[3 + x]`.

Comment: @Barmar: Even then, the editor does not execute the code.

Comment: You say in the comments `//a[3]+a[5] in this case, I get a[8], and value for that index is 9` but this is bogus.  You get the sum of `a[3]` (which is 4) and of `a[5]`, which is currently 5, hence the 9.  There is no `a[8]` and you don't access it — which is a good thing!

Comment: @user2357112 ,i tought to add in my mind behind the array indexes and values,now i see that is totally wrong and stupid....

Comment: @Olaf ,I am using a IDE called DEVc++,editor executes the code,and i had a problem which is solved now thanks

Comment: An editor is not an IDE. And it still does not execute your program. Repeating a wrong statement like a mantra does not make it true. I'd recommend you learn the basics.

Comment: @Olaf ,i will do that,thank you for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x=--a[5] ==> x=(--(a[5])) ==> x=(a[5]=a[5]-1) ==> x=(a[5]=6-1) ==> x=(a[5]=5) ==> x=5

y=a[3]+a[5] ==>y =4+5 ==> y=9

z=a[x++] ==> z=a[x] and x=x+1 ==> z=a[5] and x=5+1 ==> z=5 and x=6

finally x=6, y=9 and z=5

---

And just in case you got it wrong, a[3]+a[5] is not equal to a[3+5] i.e a[8]. a[3]+a[5]=value at a[3] + value at a[5]

---

And also, it seems that you are mis-interpreting things quite-a-bit. Your array ***a*** has only indices ranging from **0 to 6**. Remember, value at index 8 and beyond is not 8,9,10... they are *garbage values*, maybe negative numbers too. And accessing them through things like a[8]...will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You helped me ,i thought that to add beyond of array ,but is impossible ,maybe is possible but that will be something undefined ,thank you a lot

Comment: @MarkOn1 Glad to help...!

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

```
y=a[3]+a[x];  //a[3]+a[5] in this case,i get a[8],and value for that index is 9
```

`a[8]` is what you would get if you did `a[3 + x]`, not `a[3] + a[x]`.

`a[3]` is `4`, `a[x]` is `a[5]` is `5`, so `a[3] + a[x]` = `4 + 5 = 9`.

Comment: Thank you a lot,now i see the diference